# Javascript update variable with onClick

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a simple javascript function for hours. The intention is that 2 comments are displayed under an article by default, and that 5 are added each time you click on a button.

This is my code:

```
<div id="reaction1">Comment 1</div>
<div id="reaction2">Comment 2</div>
<div id="reaction3">Comment 3</div>
<div id="reaction4">Comment 4</div>
<p onClick="reactionsfunction()">More reactions</p>

<script>
var reactionsload = 2;
function reactionsfunction(){
    reactionsload = reactionsload + 5;
}
var x = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='reaction']");
for (var i = 0; i < reactionsload; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

The for loop works perfectly, but the variable is not updated. How do I get the function to update the condition in the for loop by the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, the problem is that your loop run only **once**
when your `DOM` loaded so all you need is to run this loop each time you fire `reactionsfunction` like this

```
iterate(); // run it once after the page load
var reactionsload = 2;
function reactionsfunction(){
    reactionsload = reactionsload + 5;
    iterate();
}

function iterate(){
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='reaction']");
  for (var i = 0; i < reactionsload; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with the variable, it's just that the for loop only runs once, not every single time the p element is clicked. Instead of what you have, you could put

```js
var reactionsload = 2;
function reactionsfunction(){
    reactionsload = reactionsload + 5;
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='reaction']");
    for (var i = 0; i < reactionsload; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "block";
    }
}

var x = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='reaction']");
for (var i = 0; i < reactionsload; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="reaction1">Comment 1</div>
<div id="reaction2">Comment 2</div>
<div id="reaction3">Comment 3</div>
<div id="reaction4">Comment 4</div>
<p onClick="reactionsfunction()">More reactions</p>
```

I would also like to point out that if you add more to reactionsload, there might not be say 7 elements with div whose ids start with "reaction" so there could be errors.